# Xamarin.Auth alternative for NetStandard1.4 Project?

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal, xamarin.auth

I use NetStandard project instead of PCL class for my Xamarin.Forms 2.4 project. I was thinking using Xamarin.Auth to store token receive with MSAL and user info locally but the nuget is not compatible with NetStandard yet. 
Do we have some alternative? Can we "force" install it in NetStandard project?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.Auth is being rewritten to add support for 1.0 and 1.1. Some OAuth grants like PKCE will be forced to use 1.3 and above.
There is 1.6 version of the PCL library. Lowering .NET Standard version to less than 1.6 required too much effort, so .NET support is being added with some other features.

Comment: Where I can found the rewrited Xamarin.Auth? I currently use Standard1.4

Comment: @Pierre It is in separate branch, but it is not usable yet. I have initial HTTP abstraction for HTTP requests (.NET Standard 1.0 using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse and .NET Standard 1.1 using HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage). This part is in separate repo for easier handling and testing. It will be integrated into Xamarin.Auth.